# How do I exchange the first and last rows of my identity matrix?

Tags: c

I have the following assignment:
[image]

I created an identity matrix in C. I need to exchange the first and last row. I'm not sure how. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 

    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        { 
            //if i = j, print a 1
            if (i == j) 
                printf("%d ", 1);

            //else, print 0
            else
                printf("%d ", 0); 
        } 

        //use this to make it print on seprate lines
        printf("\n"); 


    } 
}
```

This is what I have so far. I keep getting random numbers when I try it. So I am unsure about what to change:

```
    int main() 
{ 

    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
    int ar[i][j];
    int *i0, *i4, *temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        { 
            if(i=j){
                printf("%d",1);

            }
            else{
                printf("%d",0);
            }



        i0 = &(ar[i][j]);  
        i4 = &(ar[i][j]);
        temp = i0;  
        i0 = i4;  
        i4 = temp; 
        for(x=0;x<5;x++) {   
            printf(" %d", *(i0 + x));  
            }

        printf("\n"); 

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Govind Parmar I have it below:

Comment: `int ar[i][j];` --> `i` and `j` is used before initialization.

Comment: `I created an identity matrix in C..` No, you have not. You are just displaying the number `1` and `0`. Refer any good C language book and read about the array.

Comment: That's just what my teacher called it. Can someone please help me. I have been working on this for several hours and it's due tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created an identity matrix in C. I need to exchange the first and
>   last row. I'm not sure how.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 

    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        { 
            //if i = j, print a 1
            if (i == j) 
                printf("%d ", 1);

            //else, print 0
            else
                printf("%d ", 0); 
        } 

        //use this to make it print on seprate lines
        printf("\n"); 


    } 
}
```

There is no matrix here. You are simply printing the integer 0 when `i != j` and 1 when `i == j`.

> This is what I have so far. I keep getting random numbers when I try
>   it. So I am unsure about what to change

```
int main() 
{ 

    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
    int ar[i][j];
    int *i0, *i4, *temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    { 
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        { 
            if(i=j){
                printf("%d",1);

            }
            else{
                printf("%d",0);
            }



        i0 = &(ar[i][j]);  
        i4 = &(ar[i][j]);
        temp = i0;  
        i0 = i4;  
        i4 = temp; 
        for(x=0;x<5;x++) {   
            printf(" %d", *(i0 + x));  
            }

        printf("\n"); 

        } 
    }
}
```

1. `int i` and `int j` aren't initialized so what are the dimensions of `int ar[i][j]`?
2. `int ar[i][j]` is uninitialized so what is located at any given element of the matrix?
3. You seem to think you are doing something useful with pointers here:

   ```
       i0 = &(ar[i][j]);  
       i4 = &(ar[i][j]);
       temp = i0;  
       i0 = i4;  
       i4 = temp;
   ```

   But here is what you are really doing:

   ```
       /* i0 points to the memory location of the matrix element ar[i][j] */
       i0 = &(ar[i][j]);

       /* i4 points to the memory location of the matrix element ar[i][j] */ 
       i4 = &(ar[i][j]);

       /* temp points to where i0 points...
        * which is the memory location of the matrix element ar[i][j]
        */
       temp = i0;

       /* i0 points to where i4 points...
        * which is the memory location of the matrix element ar[i][j]
        */
       i0 = i4;

       /* i4 points to where temp points...
        * which is where i0 points which is where i4 points
        * which is the memory location of the matrix element ar[i][j]
        */
       i4 = temp;
   ```

   Seriously nothing useful is accomplished here and all the pointers to point to the matrix element `ar[i][j]`
4. Then you do this:

   ```
       for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
       {   
           printf(" %d", *(i0 + x));  
       }
   ```

   which says print the contents of the memory location pointed to by `i0` plus the offset `x`...but `i0` points to an uninitialized matrix element so it is no wonder you are getting "random numbers".

What you need to do is actually create a matrix and modify it's contents:

```
int ar[5][5];

/* assign elements of matrix, make it an identity matrix */
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        if(i == j){
            ar[i][j] = 1;
         }
         else ar[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

/* print elements of matrix */
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        printf("%d ", ar[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* pointer to the first element of the matrix */
int * ptr = &ar[0][0];

/* temp variables used in swap */
int temp1 = 0;
int temp2 = 0;

/* swap first and last row */
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    temp1 = *(ptr + i);         //ar[0][i]
    temp2 = *(ptr + 4*5 + i);   //ar[4][i]
    *(ptr + i) = temp2;         //ar[0][i] = ar[4][i]
    *(ptr + 4*5 + i) = temp1;   //ar[4][i] = ar[0][i]
}

printf("\n");

/* print elements of matrix */
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        printf("%d ", ar[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Would you be able to explain how you swapped it in the last for loop?

Comment: I don't have enough room in a comment to do that so check out the comments in the code [here](http://tpcg.io/LfcKT8). Please upvote my answer if it has answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to upvote it, but it wont let me. I accepted it as my answer, though.